# Drupal 7: filter views result with listbox

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I'm working on drupal 7 website. I have a VIEWS Block List for a CustomContentType entry and I need to filter these with a listbox selection. please see the screenshot below for info.

Any idea how to make that? Appreciate helps! thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SORTED!

made the list as a view, then added a filter (state field) and then **expose it to the user**.